# Is it possible to create an invisible barrier in Ursina Engine?

Tags: python, ursina

Does Ursina allow for one to create an invisible barrier to prevent the player from falling off the map, if so, how could I do that, if not should I just add walls to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create an entity and make it `visible = False` or just make it transparent (less optimized) `color = color.rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Here is an example:

```py
barrier = Entity(model='cube', collider='box', visible=False)
```